# make function to create auto input box

Tags: php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ssc prepartion</title>
  </head>

  <body><form action="ssc.php" method="post">
    1
    <input name="name" type="text">
    <input name="submit" type="submit"value="result"></form>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
// creating php file to get the result.
<?php
   $name=$_REQUEST["name"];

   $text="user".$name;
   echo'<form action="ssc1.php" method="post">';
   for($x =0; $x <= $name; $x++) {
    echo '<label for="'. $name .'">'.$x.'</label>';
      echo '<input type="text" name="'.$text.'" ><br><br>';
   }

   echo'<input type="submit" value="result">';
   echo'</form>';
?>
```

So here I am trying to create input fields by making a small PHP function. It's working and creates input fields but the problem is after creating these input fields.

I can't figure out how to give a name or id to these input fields and how to get the values from all the fields created.

My question is how could we receive the values from these input fields after creating these all?

Comment: what you want to do? you want in js or php

Answer (score 0):

using php,on ssc1.php page you can get input values using $_POST['Name of input']

Comment: Can we do it with php